# sql server 2008 fetch max data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table

First table name is abc :

```
  c_id  c_name
   C11    C1
   C12    C2
```

and second table name is xyz

```
   c_id     m_id    amt
   C11      M11    20000
   C12      M12    50000
   C11      M13    80000
   C12      M14    10000
```

I want select max(amt) with join table and the Result is:

```
  c_id    c_name   m_id    amt
  CN11      C1     M13    80000
  CN12      C2     M12    50000
```

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT S.c_id,S.c_name,T.m_id,S.M_amt
FROM
  (
   SELECT T2.c_id,T2.c_name,T1.M_amt
   FROM 
      (
        SELECT c_id,Max(amt) As M_amt From xyz Group By c_id
      ) T1 Inner Join abc T2 ON T2.c_id = T1.c_id 
           Inner Join xyz T3 ON T3.amt = T1.M_amt 
  ) S JOIN xyz T ON S.c_id = T.C_id AND S.M_amt = T.amt
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1693f7/6)**

---

*Output would be:*

```
C_ID    C_NAME  M_ID    M_AMT
C12     C2      M12     50000
C11     C1      M13     80000
```